# Проблема с отступом в конце строки Python в цикле IF

Tags: python, if

```
import spintax
lln = 4518
if lln < 4300:
    w=str(spintax.spin("{небольшой|компактный|небольшой|компактный|аккуратный|маневренный|}"))
elif int(4300) < lln > int(4900):
    w=str(spintax.spin("{достойных размеров|среднего класса|среднего размера|достаточных размеров|прекрасно сбалансированный}"))
elif lln > 4900:
    w = str(spintax.spin("{огромный|очень большой|представительный|очень заметным|здоровенный}"))
print (w)
```

Этот фрагмент (их несколько) возвращает сразу 2 ошибки..
Во-первых, после : в строке условвия (в той же строке)он жалуется на
if lln < 4300:
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Там нет ни пробела, ничего (иногда пробел есть, пробовал так и так - ничего не меняется.
И не присваивается значения w. Никакого значения.
Вне цикла отдельной строкой переменная с такой орфорафией присваивается.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

Из-за условия `int(4300) < lln > int(4900)` у вас выпадает диапазон от 4300 до 4900, поэтому не инициируется переменная `w`, что и вызывает ошибку. Чтобы перекрыть диапазон от 4300 до 4900, можно написать `4300 <= lln <= 4900`. Последнее условие можно заменить на `else`, поскольку это перекроет весь оставшийся диапазон чисел.
int(4300) и int(4900) излишни, это и так целые числа.

```
import spintax

lln = 4518
if lln < 4300:
    w = str(spintax.spin("{небольшой|компактный|небольшой|компактный|аккуратный|маневренный|}"))
elif 4300 <= lln <= 4900:
    w = str(spintax.spin("{достойных размеров|среднего класса|среднего размера|достаточных размеров|прекрасно сбалансированный}"))
else:
    w = str(spintax.spin("{огромный|очень большой|представительный|очень заметным|здоровенный}"))
print(w)
```

```
достаточных размеров
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Замылился глаз.